# Android: How to animate between activities?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, swipe

I have a question about animations in Android. I've made an app which has a lot of products in it, you can switch products now by swiping the screen left to right (go to the next product in the list) However it just loads like any other activity now.

What I want is what a lot of other apps have as well, the swiping needs to make the old activity go left and out of the screen, while the new one comes in right at the same time.

I've searched and read a lot but I really don't know where to even begin.

My Products are activities, and this is the way they are switched now:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
     try {
         if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
             return false;
         // left to right swipe
         if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
             for(HashMap h: products) {
                 if (h.get("id").toString().equals(id)) {
                     int index = products.indexOf(h)-1;

                     if (index != -1) {
                        HashMap product = products.get(index);

                        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ProductActivity.this, "", 
                                 "Laden...", true);
                        Intent i = new Intent(ProductActivity.this, ProductActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("id", product.get("id").toString());
                        i.putExtra("profileId", profileId);
                        i.putExtra("score", product.get("score").toString());
                        i.putExtra("products", products);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                     else {
                         Toast.makeText(ProductActivity.this, "Dit is het eerste product in de lijst.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         //right to left swipe
         else if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
             for(HashMap h: products) {
                 if (h.get("id").toString().equals(id)) {
                     int index = products.indexOf(h)+1;

                     if (index != products.size()) {
                        HashMap product = products.get(index);

                        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ProductActivity.this, "", 
                                 "Laden...", true);
                        Intent i = new Intent(ProductActivity.this, ProductActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("id", product.get("id").toString());
                        i.putExtra("profileId", profileId);
                        i.putExtra("score", product.get("score").toString());
                        i.putExtra("products", products);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                     else {
                         Toast.makeText(ProductActivity.this, "Dit is het laatste product in de lijst.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         // nothing
     }
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this [Android-Viewflow library](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow).

> ViewFlow is an Android UI widget providing a horizontally scrollable ViewGroup with items populated from an Adapter.

[image: Viewflow with Circle indicators] [image: Viewflow with Title indicators]

Answer (score 2):

With [overridePendingTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) you can overwrite the next animation for the activity.
Override the methods startActivity and finish of your activities and call overridePendingTransition there.

You can specify the used animations as xml file in the anim-folder.

For the slide-in animation use something like:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
</set>
```

and for the slide-out animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Depending on the value used in fromXDelta and toXDelta you can determine the direction in which it should slide.